# what is the personality trait for someone that can't think fast, slow learner etc

Tags: adjectives

what is the personality trait for someone that can't think fast, slow learner. Writing down a character is slow sounds ok but is there any other way i could describe my story character

Comment: This is not a personality trait.

Comment: [Writing that a character is slow, no down] Please punctuate your question; this is not WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

I think *obtuseness* may be a personal trait of your character

[Obtuse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obtuseness):

> - lacking quickness of perception or intellect.(AHD)
> - mentally slow
> - not sharp or pointed (Collins)

Comment: Halfwit; not the sharpest tool in the shed; the lights are on but nobody's home, might all serve to describe people who do not use their mental powers to full capacity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, one can't be entirely sure what exactly you need. Both the title and your question start out with '*what is the personality trait...'*, but then you go on to say that it should describe 'someone that can't think fast, [who is a] slow learner, etc.' What isn't clear is whether the word should be *a)* impersonal, neutral, and purely neurological/psychiatric, or whether *b)* it should be simply negative.
(And by the way, as noted in a comment, those aren't personality traits)

The one example you'd discounted, *slow*, is defined by [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/slow) as an adjective referring to people who are "*not very smart and do not understand or notice things quickly:*"

That's nearly exactly what you're looking for, but you've discounted it, possibly due to its simplicity. So, here are some other words:

---

In case it's supposed to be academic:

Several words- *moron, imbecile, idiot, retard, cretin, etc*- formerly had scientific meanings, but much like *dumb* in the sense of mute, they've more or less lost that aspect of their meaning. Now, most of them are 'softer,' with the exception of *retard*, which is still offensive.

These terms have been replaced by *intellectually disabled*, which is defined by *[AAIDD.org](https://www.aaidd.org/intellectual-disability/definition)* as "*a condition characterized by significant limitations in both intellectual functioning and adaptive behavior that originates before the age of 22.*"

Because it's a character, and we don't know the context, it's hard to know if this is what you're looking for. But if this is, indeed, a character who has a developmental condition, then *intellectually disabled* is probably the word to use, unless there's a specific neurological impairment that the character has- in which case, if it's relevant, you should specify it.

---

As for words that are plain old negative:

There's *fool*. A *fool* is "a person lacking in judgment or prudence," while a person who is *foolish* is "having or showing a lack of good sense, judgment, or discretion." (Merriam-Webster: [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fool),[2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foolish))

A *stupid* person is, as [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stupid) scathingly puts it, "slow of mind... given to unintelligent decisions [and] acting in an unintelligent or careless manner; [is] lacking intelligence or reason, [whose choices are] marked by or resulting from unreasoned thinking or acting."

But those are a little too generic. More useful, perhaps, would be members of the *-witted* family, which are somewhat more specific:

> **slow-witted**, *adj*.: not smart and therefore slow to notice or understand things ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/slow-witted))

> **half-witted**, *adj*.:stupid ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/half-witted))

> **dim-witted**, *adj*.:stupid ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dim-witted))

(I'm a little disappointed with the people who write the definitions at Cambridge)

> **thick-witted**, *adj*.: dull or slow of mind ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thick-witted))

There are some rarer ones too, comb through the list yourself [here](https://onelook.com/?w=*witted&ls=a) (not all of them are negative). The two most interesting ones are also included; I separated them because they're a little less common.

There's quarter-witted, defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quarter-witted) as "*half as bright as a half-wit*"

And there's thimble-witted, whose entry, bizarrely, looks like this:
[image] (From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thimblewit)- note the contradiction regarding where the word is used)

The reason I suggest using the -*witted* family is that they encompass the fact that the person is lacking in 'wits.' Wits, per Merriam-Webster, entail: "astuteness of perception or judgment...superior intellect...reasoning power...mental soundness [and] mental capability and resourcefulness."

A person without these qualities, who is lacking in them, is sort of the type of person that you've described, and the words from the -witted family do well to capture that.